# How to handle DB2 Default value for date

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

So I have a field called an Obsolete change date in a DB2 table which stores the date when a record was marked as Obsolete. I'm not able to figure out how to define this in the create table statement.

If i give default not null, it will enter a default value which is the current date which i dont want to be populated because if it got populated, it would indicate the record was made obsolete on the current date.

Also, I dont want to populate with NULL. So how can i handle this situation?

Comment: It's not clear how we can guess what date you should use as the default. You've already eliminated NULL and CURRENT DATE, and those seem to be the two logical choices. Anything else will either be an invalid value or an incorrect date unless you already know a specific date that should be set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using a date field, so you could use the first valid date in the format date range as a default. In some places IBM treats `0001-01-01` as a null date, but that only works for formats with 4 digit years. For various date formats that would be:

```
FORMAT                         START        END
4 digit years (e.g. *ISO)      0001-01-01   9999-12-31
3 digit years (e.g. *CYMD)     1900-01-01   2899-12-31
2 digit years (e.g. *YMD)      1940-01-01   2039-12-31
```

Date fields can only hold a valid date or null

Comment: So DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0001-01-01' is what I am planning to add to the date declaration. Have requested my lead for approval. Lets see.

Comment: Using the first or last date in the range are equally good choices depending on the circumstances. If the date is the endpoint in a range, I will use the last date in the range as the default `9999-12-31`. Otherwise I typically use `0001-01-01`.